# Creating a scripting language in assembly?

Tags: assembly, scripting, operating-system

I am wondering if it is possible create a scripting language (like batch) in assembly. I want to tie this into a OS I just made. I am asking today because it took 6+ hours to find nothing. Can you also give me some examples like how to display an image?

Comment: I am not sure you know what you are asking for.

Comment: One part is clear: can a scripting language be written in assembly.  The answer is yes.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Why don't you start with a simple command, like `echo` ? And if you can't figure out where to start, you'll just have to go back to practicing assembly language programming some more first.

Answer (score 2):

Every program that can be executed on given computer, can be written in assembly language.

Even more - it can be written better, smaller and faster than in other programming languages.

So, the answer is **yes**. The scripting language can be written in assembly language.

The big question is: Are you able to write such scripting language interpreter in assembly?